# Questions about Hebrew names

Tags: support, scope

Are questions of the form "What is the origin of name X" considered on-topic, since many of those names originated from Tanach and Shas?

Comment: In general, things are **not** on-topic only because their answers may have to do with Judaism. Personally, I think a better question is: "Are questions of the form 'What is the origin of name X' considered on-topic, since naming a baby is an act of Judaism?"

Comment: Some old chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=26986095#26986095 followed by http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=27002695#27002695 . The latter refers to even older chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/conversation/scope-a-continuation-of-the-comments-on-http-meta-judaism-stackexchange-com-a

Comment: See also http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4225